# Spring Security allow each user to see their own profile but none else

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, authorization

In Spring MVC with Spring Security, is it possible to achieve this?

*@Override WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure(HttpSecurity)*

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/users/{authentication.principal.username}").hasAnyRole(ADMIN, MANAGER)
            .antMatchers("/users/**").hasRole(ADMIN)
            .anyRequest().authorized()
    ...
}
```

`/users/**` is a restricted area and should be accessible by admins only. But managers should still be able to see their own profile (`/users/user_with_manager_role`), and only their own profile, not those of any other users (regardless of their role).

---

## Solution

I've found a solution in Andrew's answer. My Code now looks like this:

*WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) // added this annotation
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

*@Override WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure(HttpSecurity)*

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            // removed /users handling
            .anyRequest().authorized()
    ...
}
```

*UsersController*

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController
{
    @GetMapping("{username}")
    @PreAuthorize("authentication.principal.username == #username) || hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public String usersGet(@PathVariable("username") String username)
    {
        // do something with username, for example get a User object from a JPA repository
        return "user";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not edit the solution into your question. Just add a new answer to your question. Hence, I rolled back your edit.  You could copy your answer from the history to add a new answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible: when this configuration is being set up, it has no info about `{authentication.principal.username}` which will be resolved at some point in future.

But Spring gives you a bunch of built-in [method security expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#method-security-expressions) you can annotate your methods with.

Starting from a simple expression like `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")`, you might end up with a custom one:

```
@XMapping(path = "/users/{username}")
@PreAuthorize("@yourSecurityService.isMyPage(authentication.principal, #username)")
public void yourControllerMethod(@PathVariable String username);
```

`@yourSecurityService.isMyPage(authentication.principal, #username)` refers to your `@Service` method `public boolean isMyPage(Principal, String)`.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/myself").hasAnyRole(ADMIN, MANAGER)
            .antMatchers("/users/**").hasRole(ADMIN)
            .anyRequest().hasAnyRole(ADMIN, MANAGER)
    ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/myself", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Profile getMyself() {
    // return the profile of the loged in user
}
```

With this manager and admins can get their own profile and admins can also request other profiles with `/users/{username}`.